# git pull with shell_exec

Tags: php, git, ssh

I am trying to set up an automatic `git pull` on a shared server that gets triggered when I push to a github repo.

I set up the github  repo and I can push/pull from my local machine and as well when I'm logged in via ssh on the server.

When I type `git pull` in the console, it works like a charm and the files get updated. But when I use php shell_exec I get an error message:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

This is the content of the php file I call:

```
$output = shell_exec('git pull 2>&1');
echo "<h1>Github pull</h1>";
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ssh into the server you are using another OS user. The web server process probably has its own user. You need to add the key of your git server to the list of known hosts of that webserver user.

Comment: I generated a ssh key on the remote server (with ssh-keygen) and added the publickey to my github account. I can git pull from the remote server when I'm logging in via ssh. The first time, there was a message that the key was  added to the list of known hosts. Is there a separate user for the shell_exec command?

Comment: Yes, shell_exec runs as the user that runs the PHP process. See the manual for additional explanations. http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: I added `echo get_current_user();` to my php file, and it gives me the user xyz1234, the user for the ssh is called ssh-xyz1234. I can't figure out how or what I need to do to add the key to the xyz1234 user

Comment: btw I do not have root access

Comment: Is it a shared host? You might want to contact your server administrator.

Comment: Yes, I think so. I will contact the administrator then.

Comment: I contacted them, looks like that it doesn't work then, since the account has no root rights. Thank you anyways, I assume the answer would solve the problem otherwise.

Comment: I tried my luck today with a fresh mind ... I just made a `.shh` folder in the highest directory the xyz1234 user can access via FTP and copied the files from my ssh-xyz1234 account `.ssh` folder in there (with permissions 700). It works now, but I'm not sure if I have introduced any severe security holes this way.